# What is the Destroyer's power source?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, technology, thor-marvel, asgardians

In 'Thor', Odin had a 12' tall armored robot called 'The Destroyer' guarding the weapons vault. The Destroyer is composed of overlapping and articulating metal strips. When it's about to attack it emits a distinctive whirring, spooling up sound as it starts glowing yellow from the inside and its face panels open. Its primary weapon seems to be some kind of yellow disintegrating type force beam that it shoots from its 'face'. Has there been any information disclosed about what its power source may be?

[image: http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140208042222/marvelmovies/images/e/e2/Destroyer-Thor.png]

This question is focused on The Destroyer's technology/power source as presented on screen unless they're planning to introduce the Fourth Host of Celestials and the Skyfather gods (e.g. Zeus, Osiris, Shiva, etc.)

Comment: I believe the answer is Odin's magic, but I don't have time to write a proper answer right now.

Comment: Expanding on my comment, it shoots similar blasts as Gungnir, Odin’s spear. It is shown to be at the behest of whoever holds Gungnir (first Odin, later Loki). The MCU has yet to establish how or when the spear was created, except that it was used by Bor, Odin’s father.

Comment: Arc Reactor imbued with Odinforce..

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: **Magic**.

Long answer: The Asgardian culture has a very advanced technology, married with magic. Thor remarked that they considered technology and magic to be "one and the same thing." 
This is the same culture that created the hammer Mjolnir, the Tesseract, and Bifrost the Rainbow Bridge. They also must have a power source of some kind, thought we never find out what they are. The Destroyer, on the surface, seems more technological than other Asgardian magic/tech, but there is no reason to think it is any different. It is safe to assume that Asgard has access to a nearly inexhaustible power source that can be harnessed in different ways.

Comment: Just one point, but the Asgardians didn't invent the Tessaract, at least not since it's been retconned as one of the Infinity Stones (ahem...Gems), which are stated in Thor 2 to be relics from the previous universe.